# Test Environment on my PC for php website

Tags: wamp

I've spent the last few days trying to setup a test environment on my PC using WAMP to test a basic php/html website I have that I want to make a few basic changes on.

Now I am no programmer, infact a long way off, I dont know code at all. Its partly for this reason that I want to do changes in test mode, so ensure I dont screw things up.

So I finally got wamp up and running, but Im getting fatal errors all the time. I thought Id just dump all the files in the www/ folder and Bob would be my uncle. Of course its not that simple.

Is there any easy way I can do this instead of using WAMP?

After changing some of the path codes in the index.php file, I am now getting this error

( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'AutomotiveClass' not found in C:\wamp\www\repairservicemanuals.com\index.php on line 5

I dont get it because there is no file called AutomotiveClass, however there is a file called Automotive.Class .

Any help would be appreciated, either with what im doing wrong above, or a simpler way I can do this instead of wamp perhaps??

Thanks in advance from a n00b!

Answer (score 0):

You should look into **index.php** at line 5.